# formik radio button validation issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

Using formik with a validationSchema, `type: 'checkbox'` works fine, but `type: 'radio'` does not. With `Yup.boolean().required()`, when i check the checkbox, the submit button is successfully enabled, but when I select the radio button, the submit button remains disabled.

Since I need radio button functionality, to simulate it with a checkbox I created an `onChange` method to disable the checkbox when it's checked, but then the submit button is not enabled when it's checked, just like the issue with using a radio button.

I am using formik 1.5.8, but I upgraded to 2.x to test it, but with the same results.

Based on the formik docs, there is support for radio buttons, but I cannot figured out why it is not working for me

Below is the contrived code I am using, but only use either the radio button or the checkbox, not both at once, but both code examples are included

```js
class Login extends React.Component {
  LogInSchema = () => {
    const vs = Yup.object().shape({
      captcha: Yup.boolean().required(),
    });
  };

  // to simulate a radio button; once it's selected, you can't unselect it
  handleChange = event => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      event.target.disabled = true;
    }
  };

  renderFocusTrappedForm = () => {
    return (
      <FocusTrap>
        <Form>
          <FormRadio name='captcha' />

          {/* doesn't enable the submit button when checked */}
          <Field
            name='captcha'
            value='captchaToggle'
            type='radio'
            checked={this.props.formik.values.captcha}
          />

          {/* enables the submit button when checked, but only when no custom onChange is passed */}
          <Field
            name='captcha'
            value='captchaToggle'
            type='checkbox'
            onChange={this.handleChange} // prevents the submit button from enabling
            checked={this.props.formik.values.captcha}
          />
          <button>Login</button>
        </Form>
      </FocusTrap>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Formik
        initialValues={this.props.initialValues}
        validationSchema={this.LogInSchema}
        onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
        render={this.renderFocusTrappedForm()}
      />
    );
  }
}

compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
  withFormik({
    mapPropsToValues: props => ({
      captcha: 'captchaToggle',
    }),
  }),
)(Login);
```

Comment: Possibly radio input requires a value attribute.

Comment: yea I have values set...  just forgot it in the example. will update

Comment: Should `captcha: Yup.boolean().required()` now be `captcha: Yup.string().required()`?

Comment: I tried `string` with the same results, but the formik docs show using `boolean` for radio groups

Comment: CORRECTION... it did work :) i had some other changes i had to revert. im not sure why all the docs/examples use `bool` , but did you suggest using string because the value of the radio is a string?

Comment: Yep. Seems like it would be testing against whatever value would be submitted.